# possibility, importance and order-optimality of algorithms

Tags: computational-complexity

Evaluate below claims of the problems and their algorithms in terms of
possibility, importance and order-optimality.

- Problem A has worst-case lower bound $\Omega(n^{2})$ and there is an algorithm with $W(n) \in \mathcal{O}(n)$.
- Problem B has sharp worst-case lower bound $\Omega(n^{2})$ and there is an algorithm with $W(n) \in \mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! What have you tried, and where are you stuck? People may try help you understand things, but generally don't want to do your homework for you.

Comment: what is the differences between worst-case lower bound and sharp worst-case lower bound ?